# Depdrop and Dynamic Form Issue with update

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I'm Having a bit of a issue with Depdrop from Kartik-v and Dynamic Form from Wbraganca. The problem is when I load the update form, the data isn't loaded into the second dynamic field. Until i add a new row then the data is shown.

[image: Image on the problem].

It doesn't give any error. All I want is for the data to be shown on the second row and so on.

Code in the form

```
<?php $catList=ArrayHelper::map(Hs::find()->all(), 'hscode', 'hscode' );?>
          <?= $form->field($modelsItems, "[{$i}]hscode")->dropDownList($catList, ['id'=>'cat-id','prompt'=>'Select...']);?>   
        </div>                                       

        <div class="col-sm-6" style="width: 200px">

           <?= $form->field($modelsItems, "[{$i}]hsproduct")->widget(Depdrop::classname(), [

               'options'=>['id'=>'product-id'],               
                'pluginOptions'=>[
                'placeholder' => FALSE,
                'initialize' => true,
                'depends'=>['cat-id'], // the id for cat attribute               
                'url'=>  Url::to(['hs/subcat']),                   
                ]

                ]);
                  ?>
        </div>          

        <div class="col-sm-6" style="width: 170px">

             <?php $companylist=ArrayHelper::map(Company::find()->all(), 'company', 'company' );?>
          <?= $form->field($modelsItems, "[{$i}]company")->dropDownList($companylist, ['id'=>'company-id','prompt'=>'Select...']);?>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6" style="width: 170px">
             <?= $form->field($modelsItems, "[{$i}]variety")->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [

                'options'=>['id'=>'cp-varitey'], 
                'pluginOptions'=>[
                'placeholder' => FALSE,
                'initialize' => true,
                'depends'=>['company-id'], // the id for cat attribute             
                'url'=>  Url::to(['company/subcat2'])
                ]

                ])->label('Variety');   

                  ?>    
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who having this same problem i solve it by changing the id. The first ID was cat-id but when you create a new dynamic field the id then change to cat-0--id for some reason. The way i solve it was by changing the id to this
'id'=>"cat-".$i."--id" and should do this for the rest of the id. My product id now is 'id'=>"product-".$i."--id".

I hope this helps some one. Thanks